# Using Eclipselink JPA : How do you set deploy-on-startup in persistence.xml

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I am using Eclipselink in glassfish to deploy an application and I'd like to use the new Eclipse 2.3 property **DEPLOY_ON_STARTUP** to speed up my things a little. I am using Netbean 7.0 and glassfish 3.1.1 for my development.

My question is: How can I set this up in Persistence.xml? I tried the following and it couldn't deploy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"....

  <persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="JTA">   
    <jta-data-source>myDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>      

    <properties>
       <DEPLOY_ON_STARTUP>True</DEPLOY_ON_STARTUP>
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

If I have to set this property in code, how do I do that? the eclipselink wiki says:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu-name", props);
```

But I am using @EJB annotation and I don't manage the EntityManagerFactory or entity in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach does not work, because elements inside properties-element should be property-elements, which are name-value -pairs. Try

```
<property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="True" />
```

instead. I am not sure does it give such a speed improvement what you are searching, according javadocs:

> This may increase startup time of a JavaEE server, but will avoid the
>   first request from hanging as the persistence unit is deployed.

Comment: thanks. it works. my first web service call is always slow. by adding this, hopefully it will speed up a little bit.